# PHP-Error on Mediawiki1.7 Startup-Error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, mediawiki

I'm trying to set up `mediawiki 1.7` on an `Ubuntu 20.04` system with `php 7.4` `apache2` & `mariadb` (while strictly following [this](https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-install-mediawiki-ubuntu-20-04/) tutorial), but when I try to access the site through localhost, I get the following error message (the index.php) displayed:

```
// If you are reading this in your web browser, your server is probably
// not configured correctly to run PHP applications!
//
// See the README, INSTALL, and UPGRADE files for basic setup instructions
// and pointers to the online documentation.
...
```

So far, I have:

- (re)installed `php 7.4` multiple times,
- [enabled logging](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#PHP_errors) in the php.ini, which doesn't do anything,
- set the ownership/permissions of everything in the mediawiki-directory, including the index.php (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35797694/mediawiki-installation-problems)),
- checked all php modules that should be installed,
- tried everything it with [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-mediawiki-ubuntu-20-04-apache-nginx) tutorial,
- tried everything from both tutorials again,  but this time with `mediawiki 1.5`

Comment: Did you enable php with `a2enmod`?

Comment: @mashuptwice yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling `libapache2-mod-php7.4` did the thing.

```
$ sudo apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.4 libapache2-mod-php
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.4
$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
$ systemctl reload apache2
```